# Filtering included object with OfType<T> for specific ThenInclude by type T

Tags: c#, linq

Considering the classes :

```
public class MainObject
{
    List<Base> myList;
}
public class Base
{
    int MainObjectId;
    int x;
}
public class A : Base
{
    int y;
}
public class B : Base
{
    int z;
    AnotherObject anotherObject;
}
```

With such a configuration i want to include different things depending on the type of the elements in MainObject.myList

I tried something like that :

```
var result = context.mainObjects
                    .Include(mo => mo.myList.OfType<A>())
                    .Include(mo => mo.myList.OfType<B>()).ThenInclude(b => b.anotherObject)
                    .Where (mo => mo.Id == paramId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then i tried with 2 distinct queries :

```
var resultForA = context.mainObjects
                .Include(mo => mo.myList.OfType<A>())
                ..Where(mo => mo.Id == paramId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var resultForB = context.mainObjects
                .Include(mo => mo.myList.OfType<B>()).ThenInclude(b => b.anotherObject)
                ..Where(mo => mo.Id == paramId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

None of it works.

Is there a way to filter included object with OfType to have specific sub inclusion based on the type  ?

**EDIT** : i already solved the issue by doing something like this

```
var ListOfA = context.BaseObjects
               .OfType<A>()
               .Where(a => a.MainObjectId == id)
               .ToList();

var ListOfB = context.BaseObjects.Include(b => b.anotherObject)
               .OfType<B>()
               .Where(b => b.MainObjectId == id)
               .ToList();
```

But i still wonder if there is a way to do it in one query ? Or 2 but starting with MainObject ?

Comment: The SQL that this is going to generate is going to be horrific, and perform miserably at any scale. You should try rethinking your problem. Most likely, lazy loading manually in a single pull from the database will be your best bet.

Comment: Totally agree! First of all, i hate those databases based on generic object... that's not what databases are good for. But i'm working on project with some flows like this... and i try to deal with it. If i really had the choice i will refacto the database/dal/model objects to avoid such issues. But... considering this is not an option... i was wondering if it was possible or not... for the record you know :) i'm pretty sure the generated SQL... if possible, will be horrible, considering it is also done with EF Core for more flavours :)